# Using @Autowired and @Qualifier in the Controller to change datasource for the Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to using Spring boot, and currently running into an issue.

I have an application with 3 layers, Controller, Service and Repository.
TL:DR, find a diagram of my setup here:

[3Tier setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxBZD.png)

So how do I make this work? Being able to switch around the repository in the controller class?

The controller calls the service, which then uses classes in the repository to return the correct data (after doing logic magic when needed). I am also using Hibernate and H2 inmemory to make SQL connections easier, however for testing purposes I would like to have hardcoded data and methods in another repository class. My controller uses the H2 inmem datasource via the service, and my test-class uses the hardcoded-datasource.

Using simple dependency injection I can add the required respository class to the service class-constructor, and depending on either using the test-class or controller class this works fine.

However, I would like to use the `@Autowired` annotation, and found out that you can use `@Qualifier` in the service class to switch between the repo classes that get autowired. However, I don't want to do this in the service class (have it hard coded there) but do it dynamically and let the datasource choice be injected by the controller or test class.

Is this even possible, and how should I do this?

Comment: Don't, please don't as that beats the purpose of DI. Just create the repo you want to use in a special configuration so that there is only a single repo to autowire.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@service` annotation on the top of ServiceImpl class
and then `@autowired` Service in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

your package structure should be as follows:

- entity
- repository
- service and service implements
- controller

example for entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class NameEntiy implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name_column_in_your_database")
private String data;

// constructors, getter, setter, hascode, equals and string methods
}
```

example for Repository:

```
@Repository("nameEntityRepositoryQualifier")
public interface INameEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<NameEntity, Long> {

}
```

example for service:

```
public interface INameEntityService {
    public void save(NameEntity entity);
    //yours methods
}
```

example for service implements:

```
@Service("nameEntityServiceQualifier")
public class NameEntityServiceImpl implements INameEntityService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("nameEntityRepositoryQualifier")
    INameEntityRepository nameEntityRepository ;

    @Override
    public void save(NameEntity entity) {
       nameEntityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

example for controllers:

```
@Controller or @RestController
@RequestMapping("/pathController")
public class YourController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("nameEntityServiceQualifier")
    private INameEntityService nameEntityService;

    //yours controller methods
}
```